# replace sql query for hql

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

Tnis query must be return List!!!!
I want to know how to rewrite this SQL query for HQL:

```
select candidate.* from candidate inner join candidate_skill on candidate.id = candidate_skill.candidate_id inner join skill on candidate_skill.skill_id = skill.id
where skill.id = 1
```

I want to get a candidate object (instead of `candidate.*`), and I want to replace `skill.id = 1` with a skill object.

Comment: Can you show mapping of your entities?

Comment: many_to_many between candidate and skill.  Do you need code?

Comment: public class Candidate extends Person {
  private Set<Skill> skills = new HashSet<Skill>();
  @ManyToMany
  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
  @JoinTable(name = "candidate_skill", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "candidate_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "skill_id"))
  //@XmlElement
  public Set<Skill> getSkills() {
   return skills;
  }
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't this work?

```
from Candidate as candidate
  left outer join candidate.skills as skill
    where skill.id = 1
```

Comment: by this query I get Object, which inject skill and candidate

Comment: I want to get list of Candidate object only

Comment: if I write so, I get NPE